# generator function confusion in returned value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I read about generator function, I thought it's more or less the same with async await, but the expected result is different than the actual result.

```js
function* adding() {
  var result = 1 + 1
  return 20 + (yield result)
}

var sum = adding()
console.log(sum.next()) // not returning 22 but 2?
console.log(sum.next(10)) // where is 30 come from?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yield` keyword *pauses* the generator function. When you call `.next()` for the first time, the interpreter goes through the generator until it encounters the first `yield`. The generator will pause there, and return the expression that follows the `yield` to the caller of `.next()`. So, since `result` starts out at 2, `yield result` results in the first `.next()` call returning 2.

When you call `.next()` with an expression, that expression gets substituted into the generator function where the last paused `yield` was. So, when `.next(10)` is called, this line here:

```
return 20 + (yield result)
```

turns into

```
return 20 + (10)
```

because `10` is what was passed to `.next()`. So, at the end, `20 + 10` is returned, which is 30.

As you can see, generators are *quite different* from `async`/`await`, though they both deal with controlling asynchronous program flow.